# I want to test whether knowledge of calcium is associated with higher dietary intakes between 5 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I am comparing calcium intake among 5 groups and want to test whether their knowledge of calcium is associated with a higher intake. I have asked 3 questions to assess knowledge e.g. do they know the RDA for calcium, do they know why we need calcium etc.  Is a 3 way anova correct? The group sizes are unequal.

#### Details

I carried out a food frequency questionnaire and I have tallied all that up and carried out a one way anova test to compare the means between the 5 groups.  I am happy with that.  I now want to see whether there is an association between higher intakes and knowledge of calcium. I have 3 questions. 2 of which are likert style ie of they say strongly agree with the two statements then it shows they have good knowledge. I have coded the answers and transferred into excel. Do I just carry out individual one way anova tests for each question?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Rachel.  A test uses data.  Could you therefore tell us what kinds and amounts of data you have?  In particular, how do you measure calcium intake, among how many subjects per group, and how many times per subject?

Comment: Hi. There are 68 respondents, broken into 5 different groups. I want to compare answers on 3 Likert questions (independent variables?) with one dependent variable ie. dietary calcium intake.